# Unable to click on a button through any object locators?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to execute below Selenium Web driver script, But I am getting

> org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not
>   currently visible

```html
<span class="button-inner">Login</span>
```

```
@Test
public void BrowserInvocation() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\DOGETHER\\Desktop\\Website\\chromedriver.exe");
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    ChromeDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://phasorlab-web-dev.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/");     /*Get URL */
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(65, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.findElementByXPath("//span[@class='button-inner']").click();
    //driver.findElementByClassName("button-inner").click();

    //driver.findElementByTagName("[text()='Login']").click();
```

Comment: Html code of login button <span class="button-inner">Login</span>

Comment: Always test your locators in the browser using the dev console, e.g. in Chrome press F12. In the console use `$x()` to test XPaths and `$$()` to test CSS selectors. An example, `$x("//span[@class='button-inner']""//span[@class='button-inner']")`. If it returns 0, you know there's something wrong with your locator. If it returns 1, you are good to go. If it returns more than 1, you will need to verify that the element you are looking for is the first element returned. If it's not, you will need to craft a new locator.

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems with your locators.

1. Your XPATH `//span[@class='button-inner']` identifies two nodes on the DOM. The first node is hidden and hence the exception `ElementNotVisibleException`. Same is case with `driver.findElementByClassName("button-inner")`
2. `findElementByTagName("[text()='Login']")` is incorrect because `findElementByTagName` only needs the tag name and is mostly used when you want to get a list of elements of a particular tag. For example, driver.findElementByTagName("a") would give you a list of all the links on the page

**Solution:**
Using the XPATH `//span[@class='button-inner' and text()='Login']` uniquely identifies the right element.
Or simply `//span[text()='Login']`

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[text()='Login']")
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use explicit wait for handling the exception, e.g. if WebDriver instance is driver.

```
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,//mention the time);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(//mention the By locator));
```

Refer following [link](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) to see available expected conditions for explicit wait.

Answer (score -1):

The text login is in uppercase "LOGIN".
 so try this:-
//span[text()='LOGIN']
The right way is to use the ID of the element because there are higher chances of text to get change.